# Prob comparing pointers and integer in C

Tags: c, signals

Hi I have a problem with this code. When i am using this function I have no warnings.   :

```
    void handler(int sig){
   switch(sig) {
     case SIGINT : { click++; fprintf(stdout,"SIGINT recu\n");
                           if( click == N){
                             exit(0);
                           }
   }
     case SIGALRM : fprintf(stdout,"SIGALRM received\n");
                    exit(0);
     case SIGTERM:  fprintf(stdout,"SIGTERM received\n");
                     exit(0);


  }
  }
```

But when i rewrite the function with this new version, I have a " **comparison between pointer and integer**" warning on the if statement:

```
void handler( int sig){
   printf("Signal recu\n");
    if( signal == SIGINT){
     click++;
     fprintf(stdout,"SIGINT received; Click = %d\n",click);
     if(click == N){
      fprintf(stdout,"Exiting with SIGINT\n");
       exit(0);
     }
   } else if(signal == SIGALRM){
      fprintf(stdout,"SIGALRM received\n"); 
      exit(0);
   } else if(signal == SIGTERM){
     fprintf(stdout,"SIGTERM received\n"); 
     exit(0);
   }
```

Can someone tell me where is the prob?

Comment: `click == N` what type is N? `signal == SIGINT` what types are signal and SIGINT? Also, what line is the warning reported on?

Comment: How are "click", "signal", and "N" defined?

Comment: click is a global variable initialized to zero, N is a constant.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the second code, you are comparing `signal`, which is not even a local variable in the code.  In fact, `signal` as you've used it is probably referring to [the `signal` function](http://linux.die.net/man/2/signal).

In contrast, in the first code, you are `switch`ing on `sig`, which is an `int` parameter to the function.

Comment: Yes, `signal()` is in fact a function.

Comment: Yes, `signal` is a function, and it's *probably* what `signal` is in the above code... but for all we know, he didn't `#include <signal.h>` but instead did `extern int SIGINT; /* ... */ void* signal = malloc(3);`.

Comment: You are totally right. In the second bunch of code, I should compare sig variable and not signal which is function. 
It's a careless mistalke. My bad ;)
Thanks for your answer ;)

Answer (score 4):

In the second block you are comparing against `signal`, not `sig`. Since `signal` isn't declared locally, you're actually comparing against a pointer to the `signal()` function.

Answer (score 1):

In second version you are comparing signal which is not defined in your function to SIGINT etc. signal is declared elsewhere to be a pointer.

Perhaps you meant to rename sig in the function prototype to signal